# Areas of two triangles.

Tags: triangles, area

The diagram shows two identical triangular pieces of paper A and B. The side
lengths of each triangle are in the proportion 3, 4 and 5. Each triangle is folded along a line
through a vertex, so that the two sides meeting at this vertex coincide. The
regions not covered by the folded parts have respective areas SA and SB. If
SA+SB=39, find the area of the original triangular piece of paper A.

[image: Figure for above question]

I understand that the triangles which cover each other, become congruent triangles. But, I am stuck here.   I do not know how to proceed.   Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question now.

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big triangle is 3-4-5

The yellow triangle is a right triangle.  And it shares an angle with the big triangle, so it must be similar to the big triangle.  Lets call that angle $\alpha$

The leg adjacent to $\alpha$ in $A = 4$

The leg adjacent to $\alpha$ in the yellow triangle $= 5-3 = 2$

Each side is half as long as the corresponding side in A.

Comment: Considering the sides of the big triangles as 3x, 4x and 5x. So, the corresponding sides of the smaller triangles are 1.5x, 2x and 2.5x.   Now, SA+SB=0.5*(2x)(1.5x)+0.5*(2x)(1.5x)=39   =>   x = sqrt(13).   So, area of big triangle A = 0.5*(4x)(3x) = 0.5(4)(3)(13) = 6*13 = 78.   So, area of original piece of triangle A = 78.   Is this correct?   Please advise.

Comment: In $SA$ the side lengths are $\frac {3}{2}x, \frac {4}{2}x, \frac {5}{2}x.$ In SB  they are $\frac {3}{3}x, \frac {4}{3}x, \frac {5}{3}x$  The areas of each then are $\frac {6}{4}x^2, \frac {6}{9}x^2$ and $\frac 64 x^2 + \frac 69 x^2 = 39$  or $\frac {13}{6} x^2 = 39 \implies x^2 = 18$ and the big triangle has area $6x^2 = 108$

Comment: Thank You very much for the Answer.   However, please explain why the sides in SB are 3x/3, 4x/3 and 5x/3 ?

Comment: ...   I understood now ...thanks again Doug     :-)